# CSS: white-space: nowrap works differently in IE11

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-11

Please find below the code:

```css
.spc {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="spc"></textarea>
```

With the above code when I Start typing spaces into the textarea field in IE 11 Notice that the cursor doesn't move.
This problem does not occur in Chrome.
Could you please explain what might be the reason for this?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with [tag:javascript]. For that matter, it has nothing to do with [tag:css3] either. `white-space: nowrap` is CSS 2.1.

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm the behavior. Interesting. And it drives Firefox nuts, the cursor jumps to the right before returning to the left and then seems to be similar to IE11.

Comment: The use of `white-space: nowrap` in a  `<textarea>` has no sense. For that reason you have `<input type="text">` that makes exactly the same (single line).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in Firefox works fine this code.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Not for me (Firefox 47.0).

Comment: Just update to Firefox 47.0.1 and it works fine, the cursor stay at the right side when I am writing. However, this textarea have no sense for me. If he wants a single line form control the <input type="text"> fits perfectly

Comment: While it's interesting in a kind of academic way that it doesn't work properly in IE11 (at least), see @Marcos' point: What is your use case for a `textarea` with `white-space: nowrap`?!

Comment: I currently have a text area with a max word count field of 256 chracters. But here when I Start typing spaces into the freetext field I Notice that the cursor doesnt move but the count decrements. This weird behavior is observed only in IE 11

Comment: Still have no sense. Use `<input type="text">` instead of `<textarea>` and remove the CSS. I can't say it more clear.

Comment: I need the input field to be a textarea, hence I am using this. The question is why this weird behavior is exhibited in IE 11??

Comment: Ok. The weird behaviour it's not strange since we are talking about IE11. Maybe a bug, maybe a superbug, maybe a weird bug. I will search about it.

Comment: There are tons of articles in google of people that have the same issue, it's a bug. The most common problem is the inheritance of `white-space` from a parent.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in this scenario as here there is no such inheritance.